# observe multiple IObservable parallel

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive

I have a `Session` and a `Service`. The `Service` can have multiple `Sessions`. Each `Session` got a `IObservable<SessionState>` property.

What I want to achieve:

If all `Session.States` are `NotConnected`, then `Service` should call `Foo()`. I already got a solution, but I don't think that is the `reactive way` how to do it.

```cs
public class Session
{
    public SessionState ActualState => _SessionStateSubject.Value;
    public IObservable<SessionState> State => _SessionStateSubject.AsObservable();
    private readonly BehaviorSubject<SessionState> _SessionStateSubject = new BehaviorSubject<SessionState>(SessionState.NotConnected);

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _SessionStateSubject.OnNext(SessionState.Initializing);
    }
}

public class Service
{
    private List<Session> _Sessions = new List<Session>();

    public void SubscribeToChannels()
    {
        foreach (Session session in _Sessions)
        {
            session.State.TakeUntil(s => s == SessionState.NotConnected).Subscribe(state =>
            {
                // check all other sessions
                if(_Sessions.All(s => s.ActualState == SessionState.NotConnected))
                    Foo();
            });
        }
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        // this should be called if all of them are 'NotConnected'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CombineLatest` to get a list of the last known states of all items, any time there's a change. From there on, it's just checking if all states are `NotConnected`.

```
    public IDisposable SubscribeToChannels()
    {
        return Observable
               .CombineLatest(_Sessions.Select(s => s.State))
               .Subscribe(states =>
               {
                   if (states.All(s => s == SessionState.NotConnected))
                        Foo();
               });
    }
```

Comment: Ah I forgot `CombineLatest` ‍♂️ Thanks for your solution. I also updated my `query` and added `Where()` and `Take()` (because if once `NotConnected`, no more new status updats are pushed). So now I'm not sure which one is better in performance.

Comment: `TakeUntil` takes in a predicate.